# In which point of the code the loop ends?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I was exploring github for best practices of Selenium Webdriver framework and I found code as below:

```js
async function waitForVisible(driver, locator, retries = 3) {
    try {
        const element = await driver.findElement(locator);
        await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), WAIT_TIME_OUT)
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`Element "${locator.toString}" is not visible after maximum retries, error message: ${err.message}`)
    }
    await driver.sleep(WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_RETRY);
    return waitForVisible(driver, locator, retries - 1)
  }
```

As you see, it looks like the function recurses infinitely, and only end by throwing an exception. But I was testing this code a lot and I noticed that it ends without throwing the exception.

The question is how it is possible and in what point/case the "loop" ends? I try to understand the code as much as possible.

Comment: the fact that the return statement doesn't `return await waitForVisible...` is the key - though, I can't see where `retries` is even checked for hitting `0` - so, yeah, ugly code that kind of makes no sense - having trouble seeing how that could possibly return anything useful, how is it *used*?

Comment: Pardon? I don't understand the part of return statement... What is a key? I can agree that there should be `await` in `return await waitForVisible` statement but it does not change the fact that in some point the code is finished executing and ends the "loop". If it is an answer for my question, can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: yeah, it's not the key at all is it :p - that's s mystery, have you tried debugging?

Comment: If you mean debugging by using some IDE debugger then the answer is: no. If you mean using the code in some project: yes. I setup a testing project and I used the function. I created a few tests by using `mocha` and I executed this function more than one time. In any case my code didn't "stuck". It was passing through next tests

Comment: simple console.log statements scattered throughout the code to see what is happening when

Answer (score -2):

I found that using a return statement works.